# Why would ZoneAlarm warn me Stackoverflow could be phising site?

Tags: support

Here is what I got when I clicked on a migrated question from Stack to SU.
[image: Stack1]
[image: stack2]

Anything to be worried about?

Comment: So, IE huh? Anyway, *"Nothing bad has happened yet"*, and so there's definitely no problem. Right?

Comment: whoa are you using windows vista ? btw click on let us know link and give review about site

Comment: @MarkGarcia - Eh, yeah IE. And no nothing bad yet. ;) just odd, it has neve done that before and figured it should at least be posted, just in case.

Comment: @NullPonyPointer - lol, no 7. And i did do the "let us know"

Comment: sign .. since only real programmer have right to use windows vista not programmer like us :P :D

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb here and say Stack Overflow is _not_ a phishing site. I have no idea why it tripped, I'm not sure it does either.

Comment: [Related](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_oil).

Comment: This is *probably* due to an over-excited trigger on the cross-site redirect.  ("Hey, this site is redirecting you to somewhere else under a completely different domain, and they're not Google...")